# Get Id from value in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

[image]

How can I get the value `10` in the selected cell (`B8`), from the text in the `C8`?

I tried `=VLOOKUP(C8,B3:C5,1)` but don't really achieved something `#N/A` as result...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For vlookup your value to be picked should be on right side of the array so instead of storing your id in column B, store it in column D then try with you updated vlook up formula, this time it should work also put a `,False` before closing paranthesis in your forumula

Or if you dont want your id on right side, check Xlookup function [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/xlookup-function-b7fd680e-6d10-43e6-84f9-88eae8bf5929)

Comment: +1 for Xlookup advice and Vlookup

Comment: `=XLOOKUP(C8,C3:C5,B3:B5,1,FALSE)` worked, thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

@Usmaan Waheed is correct about VLOOKUP and the advice about XLOOKUP (if you have Excel 365). Another method to obtain the result is to use `INDEX` and `MATCH` functions as shown on the formula below:

```
=INDEX(B3:B5,MATCH(C8,C3:C5,0))
```

[image: Result]

Comment: INDEX function worked, alog with XLOOKUP; thanks!